# Amazon S3 GET Object

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am uploading files to S3. When I do a GET, I get an S3Object as explained below -

```
    S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
            bucketName, key));
```

I need to convert S3Object to java.io.File..

Is it that the following API is the only way I can do this -

```
S3ObjectInputStream getObjectContent()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [getObject(final GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest, File destinationFile)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest,%20java.io.File%29) method to do what you want. It will write your object from Amazon S3 into the destinationFile you provide.